# Is there any alternative of skip locked for update in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have 5 rows in table. And some of the rows are locked in some sessions .
I don't want to generate any error, Just want to wait until any row will become free for further processing

I tired with nowait and skip locked:-

1. nowait , But there is a problem with nowait. query has written in cursor , when I used "nowait" under cursor , query will return null and control will go out with an error by saying- resource busy
2. I tried with skip locked with for update-But if table contain 5 rows and all 
   5 rows are locked then it is giving error.

`CURSOR cur_name_test IS
SELECT def.id , def.name
  FROM def_map def
 WHERE def.id = In_id
   FOR UPDATE skip locked;`

Comment: why in the cursor you are using update ? are you trying to do pessimistic locking ? you want the lastest data right in the cursor query ?

Comment: I'd say put a NOWAIT of some seconds in the cursor and then use WAIT for the same amount of seconds for any consecutive query.

Comment: I think you should step back and explain what you're trying to do. You want to update these rows, so why are you trying to skip the locked ones? What error are you getting in #2?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use select for update only ? The below is being test locally in plsql developer.

in first sesssion I do the below

```
SELECT id , name
  FROM ex_employee
   FOR UPDATE;
```

in second session i run the below however it hang.

```
SET serveroutput ON size 2000
/
begin
declare curSOR cur_name_test IS
SELECT id , name
  FROM ex_employee
 WHERE id = 1
   FOR UPDATE ;

begin
for i in cur_name_test loop
      dbms_output.put_line('inside cursor');

end loop;

end;
end;
/
commit
/
```

when I commit in the first session , the lock will be released and the second session will do its work. i guess that you want , infinite wait.

However such locking mechanism (pessimistic locking) can lead to deadlocks if its not managed correctly and carefully ( first session waiting second session , and second session waiting first session).

As for the nowait its normal to have error resource busy, because you are saying for the query don't wait if there are locking. you can instead  wait 30, which will wait 30 second then output error but thats not what you want(I guess).

As for skip locked, the select will skip the locked data for example you have 5 rows , and one of them is locked then the select will not read this row . thats why when all the data is locked its throwing error because nothing can be skipped. and I guess is not what you want in your scenario.

Comment: Correct . Actually I tried with for update only , but problem here is , It is taking huge time to complete the 1 session , and waiting state for the next session. Frequently we are facing this issue , so I have decide to skip some rows and proceed further . At some extent it is working fine. But for some scenarios , where value are less , it is giving error.

Comment: @Yash well why the first session is taking lot of time? if there are some queries taking time you can tune them. logically speaking its not a good practice for a such process locking lot of time. however what its coming to my mind is doing OPTIMISTIC LOCKING. you do select for data and you do your work, before updating  , check if this data is have being changed . if not changed then you do your commit.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need to think about transaction control.

If you are doing work in a transaction then the implication is that that unit of work needs to complete in order to be valid.
What you are saying is that some of the work in my update transaction doesn't need to complete in order for the transaction to be committed.

Not only that but you have two transactions running at the same time performing operations against the same object. In itself that may be valid but
if it is then you really need to go back to the first sentence and think hard about transaction control and process flow and see if there's a way you can have the second transaction only attempt to update rows that aren't being updated in the first transaction.